# Live CSS preview possibilities?

Tags: css, laravel, ubuntu, gulp, laravel-elixir

Lately I've been working on styling my application a lot, and I had someone tell me that using a live preview would be awesome. However, I can't seem to find anything that would work in my particular work environment.

I currently work in Laravel, I have the application running on a Ubuntu PC on my local network. I devide my styling into 2 files, one for element styling and one for flexbox layout, when I save one of the files gulp/elixir triggers and compiles it from SCSS to CSS and then grabs normalize and puts it together into one large file.

Most programs like live reload and such work with checking if a file is saved locally, I save it in Sublime text 3 and it uploads it using the FTP extension, then gulp triggers and does all the magic.

I can't seem to wrap my mind around a solution, any idea's on how to get some kind of live CSS preview working?

Comment: you could use brackets editor. I believe its also available for Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BrowserSync is perfect for this, added folders for both my views and style changes (targeted the folder where gulp puts my finished stylesheet) and it worked like a charm. Easy to set up and no worries.

Answer (score 0):

I actually dont think this would be that hard. This is what I would do if I had an environment like yours.

Gulp -

I would set up a dev flag within gulp that would watch my SCSS changes.
Using [Gutil](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-util#noop) flags i would check If dev == true & trigger a FTP of the css as test.css with [gulp ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ftp)

```
.pipe(isDev ? .pipe(ftp({ /* settings here */ })  : gutil.noop() )
```

Website Javascript -

I would set up some kind of trigger based on perhaps the localstorage that you can set manually, to inject the test.css if value is true. Example;

```
if ( localStorage.getItem('dev') === true ) {
  var head = document.head,
      link = document.createElement('link')

  link.type = 'text/css'
  link.rel = 'stylesheet'
  link.href = '{url}' // test.css

  head.appendChild(link);

}
```

So all together every time you hit save on a SCSS it will build it and push it to the server & if localstorage dev is set to true your javascript should inject the test.css into the head.
This process would be slow, but it should work.